# Getting imageview size for Bitmap creation

Tags: android, android-widget, android-imageview, android-canvas

I am a programmer with a Windows background and I am new to Java and Android stuff.

I want to create a widget (not an app) which displays a chart. After a long research I know I can do this with Canvas, imageviews and Bitmaps. The canvas which I paint on should be the same as the Widget Size.

How do I know the widget size (or imageview size) so that I can supply it to the function?

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(width_xx, height_yy, Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Code Snippet:

In the timer run method:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(??, ??, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    // Create a new paint
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setStrokeWidth(1);

    // Draw circle
    // Here I can use the width and height to scale the circle
    canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 7, p);
    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, bitmap);
```

Comment: \*facepalm\*, an [*App Widget*](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) .  Two words which, together, require an answer to this question that has nothing at all to do with the answer you'd get to either one.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've learnt, you can only calculate widget dimensions on Android 4.1+. 
When on a lower API, you'll have to use static dimensions.
About widget dimensions: [App Widget Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html)

```
int w = DEFAULT_WIDTH, h = DEFAULT_HEIGHT;

if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16 ) {
    Bundle options = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(widgetId);

    int maxW = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH);
    int maxH = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT);

    int minW = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH);
    int minH = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);

    if ( context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ) {
        w = maxW;
        h = minH;
    } else {
        w = minW;
        h = maxH;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Kudos for pointing out the need to look at orientation.  But why would orientation matter when the values are named "MIN" and "MAX" ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the method:

```
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged (Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions)
```

It will be called each time you start/resize the widget.

Getting the widget width/height can be done as follows:

```
newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH)
newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH)
newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT)
newOptions.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using this:

```
private void run() {

    int width = 400, height = 400;

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p.setStrokeWidth(1);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);

    c.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, radius, p);

    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, bitmap);

    ComponentName clockWidget = new ComponentName(context,
    Clock_22_analog.class);
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
    .getInstance(context);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(clockWidget, remoteViews);
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21906166/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Bitmap image1, image2;

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom widget and set the size of wight on its onMeasure() method. And also save the size at that time so that you can use it further for image creation...

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked on Widgets, but I have some experience getting ImageView's size.

Here is some code I use:

```
public class ViewSizes {
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        boolean result = false;
        if (0 >= width || 0 >= height) {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

That's just a dummy class containing the size parameters.

```
public static ViewSizes getSizes(View view) {
        ViewSizes sizes = new ViewSizes();
        sizes.width = view.getWidth();
        sizes.height = view.getHeight();

        if (sizes.isEmpty()) {
            LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
            if (null != params) {
                int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(params.width, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
                int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(params.height, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
                view.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
            }

            sizes.width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
            sizes.height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        return sizes;
    }
```

This method calculates the width forcing a measure cycle if such has not already happened.

```
public static boolean loadPhoto(ImageView view, String url, float aspectRatio) {
    boolean processed = false;
    ViewSizes sizes = ViewsUtils.getSizes(view);

    if (!sizes.isEmpty()) {
        int width = sizes.width - 2;
        int height = sizes.height - 2;
        if (ASPECT_RATIO_UNDEFINED != aspectRatio) {
            if (height * aspectRatio > width) {
                height = (int) (width / aspectRatio);
            } else if (height * aspectRatio < width) {
                width = (int) (height * aspectRatio);
            }
        }

        // Do you bitmap processing here

        processed = true;
    }

    return processed;
}
```

This one is probably useless for you. I give just as an example - I have an ImageView and image URL, which should be parametrized with image and height.

```
public class PhotoLayoutListener implements OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    private ImageView view;
    private String url;
    private float aspectRatio;


    public PhotoLayoutListener(ImageView view, String url, float aspectRatio) {
        this.view = view;
        this.url = url;
        this.aspectRatio = aspectRatio;
    }

    boolean handled = false;
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (!handled) {
            PhotoUtils.loadPhoto(view, url, aspectRatio);
            handled = true;
        }

        ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = view.getViewTreeObserver();
        if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                removeLayoutListenerPre16(viewTreeObserver, this);
            } else {
                removeLayoutListenerPost16(viewTreeObserver, this);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void removeLayoutListenerPre16(ViewTreeObserver observer, OnGlobalLayoutListener listener){
        observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void removeLayoutListenerPost16(ViewTreeObserver observer, OnGlobalLayoutListener listener){
        observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
    }
}
```

This is just a layout listener - I want to process the image loading once the layout phase has finished.

```
public static void setImage(ImageView view, String url, boolean forceLayoutLoading, float aspectRatio) {
    if (null != view && null != url) {
        final ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = view.getViewTreeObserver();

        if (forceLayoutLoading || !PhotoUtils.loadPhoto(view, url, aspectRatio)) {
            if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
                viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new PhotoLayoutListener(view, url, aspectRatio));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the method I actually call. I give it the view and URL. The methods takes care of loading - if it can determine the view's size it starts loading immediately. Otherwise it just assigns a layout listener and start the loading process once the layout is finished.

You could strip away some parameters - forceLoading / aspectRatio should be irrelevant for you. After that change the `PhotoUtils.loadPhoto` method in order to create the bitmap with the width / height it has calculated.

Comment: Widgets run in a remote view, so this method doesn't work

Answer (score -2):

Like [Julian told us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455819/getting-imageview-size-for-bitmap-creation/9460883#9460883), you can get them like that with a bitmap of your image:

```
int width = bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();
```

Comment: Look at his example code.  He wants to *create* the bitmap, and create the Canvas that will use it.  I suggest that he wait until .onDraw() provides the Canvas.

Comment: yes, Julian is right, the bitmap needs to be created based on the Widget/imageview size, i expect something like , int width = widget.getWidth(); or int width = imageview.getWidth();